# Error Adding Login with SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, smo

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio, and I'm trying to add just a basic login. (I'm fairly new to SSMS).

I've connected to local server, and I right-click on `Security > Logins > New Login...`, and then I get a dialog that says this:

> Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)
>   Cannot read property Collation.This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

So there is the issue I'm coming up with. I'm sure its probably an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: I believe you have connected to a SQL Server 7.0 instance of SQL Server. And I think this is the first real live occurrence of this I've seen in a long, long time. Can you tell us what SQL Server services appear under Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services? I suspect you connected to the default 7.0 instance but meant to connect to a newer, named instance.

Comment: `This property is not available on SQL Server 7.0`.  Wow, SQL Server 7.0?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I'm seeing MSSQLSERVER and SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Management Studio, your connection should be to one of the following:

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
.\SQLEXPRESS
YOUR_MACHINE_NAME\SQLEXPRESS
```

And you should probably consider uninstalling that SQL Server 7.0 instance.